# mayapy/maya.standalone error: No object matches name: .aiTranslator

Tags: maya, python-standalone

When I run this in `mayapy`:

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize()
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.file("/Users/Desktop/test.ma", open=True, force=True)
```

Then I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: file: /Users/Desktop/dad.ma line 26: The camera 'perspShape' has no '.aiTranslator' attribute.
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 26: setAttr: No object matches name: .aiTranslator
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 43: The camera 'topShape' has no '.aiTranslator' attribute.
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 43: setAttr: No object matches name: .aiTranslator
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 59: The camera 'frontShape' has no '.aiTranslator' attribute.
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 59: setAttr: No object matches name: .aiTranslator
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 76: The camera 'sideShape' has no '.aiTranslator' attribute.
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 76: setAttr: No object matches name: .aiTranslator
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 90: The mesh 'pSphereShape1' has no '.aiTranslator' attribute.
file: /Users/Desktop/test.ma line 90: setAttr: No object matches name: .aiTranslator
Error reading file.
Error reading file.
```

But when I run this in maya:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.file("/Users/Desktop/test.ma", open=True, force=True)
```

Then executes just fine.

`test.ma` is just a new scene with one object in, nothing fancy. For some reason, running this trough the mayapy/maya.standalone I get this error

Comment: Seems that mtoa plugin is not loaded in your mayapy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to check if mtoa is loaded or not. If not loaded then load it before opening the file.

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize()
import maya.cmds as cmds
if  not cmds.pluginInfo("mtoa.so", q=True, loaded=True):
     cmds.loadPlugin("mtoa.so")
cmds.file("/Users/Desktop/test.ma", open=True, force=True)
```